# How to disable and enable TINYMCE with a button and Jquery

Tags: tinymce

I have a site, that when it loads, it initializes the tinyMCE, then, when you click a button, it opens a modal and while in that process, it brings some HTML into the modal.

then inside that modal, there is another button that should let you edit the content of the modal. and inside the DIV that holds the loaded HTML, there are divs with a class to make them editable by the tinyMCE.

the thing is, when you build the content of the modal and you save. everything is fine and it stores it with the format, because when you refresh the site, and load the content, everything is still with the correct format (bold,colors,etc). but then when you want to update the content, and you click the button to edit, I have an option to initialize again the tinyMCE and the contents editable zones loses their format.

now I suppose that the problem is when I initialize again the tinyMCE that causes the problem but how can I enable and disable the edition inside the modal when I click the button to make the edits?

I saw that there is an .on() and .off() functions, but I don´t understand well how to use them, is not clear enough in the documentation.

this is a sample of what I have.

```
<script>
var pathBotones = "<?=$pathBotones?>";
var modalEditor = {
mode: 'exact',
selector: '.zonaEditable',
menubar: false,
inline: true,
plugins: [
    'link',
    'autolink',
    'lists',
    'save'
],

toolbar: [
    'undo redo | bold italic underline | fontselect fontsizeselect | link',
    'forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignfull | numlist bullist'
],
valid_elements: 'strong,em,span[style],a[href]',
valid_styles: {
    '*': 'font-size,font-family,color,text-decoration,text-align'
},
powerpaste_word_import: 'clean',
powerpaste_html_import: 'clean',
content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i'
]
};
tinymce.init(modalEditor);

$(".edit-content").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
//console.log($('.editOptions').css('display'))
if ($('.editOptions').css('display') === 'none') {
    //this is supossed to enable the edition




    tinymce.init(modalEditor);

} else {
    console.log('NOOO se ve')


}
//this is supossed to disable the edition
$(".editOptions").slideToggle();
$(".deleteRowInfoBox").fadeToggle();;

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use TinyMCE's APIs to set the mode on the editor to readonly.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editormode/#set

The code would look something like:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setMode('readonly');
```

...or...

```
tinymce.get('theEditor').setMode('readonly');
```